# Storm Door Installation

Tags: repair, doors, door-frame, storm-door

I am looking at installing a 36x80 Andersen 3000 storm door. When I started looking at my current front door, it looks like there is an extra trim piece overtop of the actual door frame. Because of this extra piece (highlighted in red) there is not enough surface space to mount the storm door. I need 3/4" and what I have available is 1/2".

Is my best course of action to remove the aluminum trim, remove the extra wood trim piece, install the door, cut the trim piece back by 1/2", reinstall it and then reinstall the aluminum trim?

[Door Pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUpxs.jpg)